# Intercept Process Access using a Windows MiniFilter Driver

Tags: c, windows, kernel, driver, minifilter

I am developing a security application which should monitor activity by any process.

I successfully managed to intercept file access by installing a MiniFilter driver, thanks to the [MiniFilter sample provided by Microsoft on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/scanner).

However, I did not find any documentation about how to intercept **process** creation/termination using a Minifilter.

I would like to intercept new process creation by any parent process (which could use functions like CreateProcess, ShellExecute etc.).

I would also like to intercept process termination signals (sent by APIs like [TerminateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess)) to avoid my security program process to be killed by potential malware.

At the moment I setup a callback function in my minifilter driver which successfully intercepts file I/O operations, as instructed by the Microsoft example:

```
FLT_POSTOP_CALLBACK_STATUS ScannerPostCreate (
    _Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA CallbackData,
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _In_opt_ PVOID CompletionContext,
    _In_ FLT_POST_OPERATION_FLAGS Flags
    )
```

My question is, can I use the same callback function to intercept process access?
Or, do I need to setup a different callback function, or use an entirely different method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the minifilter is a kernel module, you can use any routine exported by kernel/HAL or other kernel modules. For example, PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine.